# How to pass variables from VBA through SQL?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to pass values from a Form into my database, via SQL:

```
Private Sub Befehl4_Click()

Dim SQL As String
Dim unique As String

unique = Forms!frm_test!PN

SQL = "INSERT INTO tab_test (Feld1) VALUES (unique)"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End Sub
```

When I execute this code from my button in my Form, `unique` isn't passed to the SQL-command. I have to type it in. When writing the SQL-command this way:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO tab_test (Feld1) VALUES (Forms!frm_test!PN)"
```

It works how expected.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`SQL = "INSERT INTO tab_test (Feld1) VALUES ('" & Forms!frm_test!PN & "')"`

Comment: That opens up the application to SQL injection, and `unique` is dimmed as a string, so this'll likely not work too, because you haven't used string delimiters.